# UIImageView и UIScrollView, как скроллить

Tags: xcode, swift, swift3, uiscrollview

Есть UIScrollView. Он не скроллится если тянуть например за кнопку, картинку и т д. Как это исправить?

Код ImageView (тут находится ScrollView)

```
import Foundation

class ImageView: UIScrollView, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var viewForImages: UIView!

var view: UIView?
let nibName = "ImageView"

required init() {
    super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    self.view = self.loadFromNib()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func loadFromNib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
    self.scrollView.delegate = self
    return view
}
}
```

Код MenuView (сюда подгружается та вью из xib)

```
import Foundation

class MenuView: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var orderButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var constraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var languageHelpButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var taxiButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var gidButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var priceButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIView!

var imgView: ImageView?

let nibName: String = "MenuView"
var view: UIView?

required init() {
    super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    self.view = self.loadFromNib()
    let const = (self.view?.frame.size.height)! - (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height-200.0)
    print("const=\(const)")
    print("view.height:\(self.view?.frame.size.height)" )
    print("screen.height:\(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)")
    self.constraint.constant = const

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

func loadFromNib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
    imgView = ImageView()
    self.imageView.addSubview((self.imgView?.view!)!)
    return view
}
}
```

Comment: все должно работать, если вы у себя не добавляли никаких кастомных обработчиков. а если добавляли, то показывайте код

Comment: @MAXMikheyenko добавил код, но впринципе вроде никаких обработчиков не добавлял

Comment: Может поможет туториал от Рея, попытаться стоит https://www.raywenderlich.com/122139/uiscrollview-tutorial

Comment: @ИсмаилХасбулатов поставил вместо картинок лейблы, так же не скролит. нужно было еще ранее упомянуть, что у меня на основной вью находится карта на весь экран. И при нажатии на точку на карте появляется вью на весь экран поверх карты. Эта вью вертикально скролится, а внутри этой выю расположена горизонтальная вью с фотографиями. И когда я пытаюсь его скролить - вью пропадает и двигается карта вместе с курсором.